# How to get data using selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get data from a website and store the html code using selenium. I wrote the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(r'http://www.example.com')
driver.page_source #get the html code
```

What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(r'http://www.example.com')
driver.page_source #get the html code

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
driver.quit()
```